# Using * sizing in a data template WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, itemtemplate

I am trying to set a * height property in an item template but I keep getting the error

```
'50*' string cannot be converted to Length.
```

Im not sure if what Im wanting to do is possible.

Please let me know if you need anymore information.

Heres my Xaml:

```
<ItemsControl Name="lstMain" ItemsSource="{Binding Sections}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <GroupBox Header="{Binding Section.SectionName}" Height="50*">
                            <StackPanel>
                                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding SubSections}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource BinderTemplate}" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </GroupBox>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the point is that Height is a `Double` data type and not a [GridLength](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.gridlength.aspx), such as grid rows and columns are.

Only GridLength supports the  star size.